# pacman archlinux install [newbie]

Tags: arch-linux

in the midst of installing archlinux on my device i made a mistake, i forgot to include "linux" in the following command.

pacstrap /mnt base **linux** linux-firmware sudo nano

now i cannot access **pacstrap** anymore, not sure why. so can i use pacman to install the missing "linux" piece? how would this command look like?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Command to install a **foo** package is:
`sudo pacman -S foo`
but this needs a *working* environment;

Starting from information provided I cannot say any more, except for: the easiest way for **you*** to *fix* the issue, is probably to start from the beginning the entire installation process.
*It is easiest to destroy and create a brand new machine than transform the current one...*

*I assume you are a newbie, if you ask a such kind of question...

Comment: thanks, i didnt even know how to quit the install process :)

Comment: Did you try CTRL+d or CTRL-c ? anyway, remember, **Archwiki** is a great place where looking for *first help*, especially: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide

Comment: ctrl c didnt work.

i just pushed the power button, so the install process got killed that way